# Virtually exact same question by different users. Should it be flagged?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, duplicate-accounts

Look at these two questions.

1. [Replacing all occurrences of an object in a Linked List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303904/replacing-all-occurrences-of-an-object-in-a-linked-list-in-java)
2. [Replacing a node in a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305528/replacing-a-node-in-a-linked-list)

It appears that the same person created two different user accounts and posted the same question from each account.

Should I flag one (or both) of these questions for moderator attention?

Comment: Flag one, link the other?

Comment: Close one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: Sadly, flagging as duplicate isn't likely if one of them doesn't have a good answer. At best just leave them be to see if any of them acrue any good answers or if both have issues that doesn't meet our quality standards.

Comment: That could also be two student have the same assignment, no?

Comment: @Scratte could be... but... given the name similarities and *exact* text matches for text that doesn't  appear to be an assignment... iunno, things aren't adding up to support that imo

Comment: @KevinB - I wonder why, when they create multiple accounts, they keep a nearly identical username? So as we can identify them easier?

Comment: first thing I do discovering reposts like that (prior to flagging) is downvote both posts - without usual fear of serial voting reversal (since user accounts are formally different). Extra downvotes help system to establish IP level blocks, making it harder to cheat (@OlegValter I think I saw it mentioned few times in Tavern chat room and in various meta comments that sock puppets surprisingly frequently keep same / similar names - probably hoping that system and curators are too stupid to catch them)

Comment: @gnat _Extra downvotes help system to establish IP level blocks, making it harder to cheat_ --> IIRC this is only if the post gets enough red flags. Then the IP is fed to Spam Ram and thus it's blocked. A post can get 50 downvotes and it wouldn't IP block the user unless it got deleted as spam or Rude/abusive.

Comment: @10Rep I am talking about [different defence mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359832/165773) against different kind of abuse. If it wasn't there than dosen college mates (along with hundred of their sock puppets) could easily block whole site by posting their homework dumps

Comment: @gnat - huh, that's quite surprising - I guess it is similar to how fishing emails can't get the grammar/spelling right most of the time.

Comment: *Sometimes*, the dupe account is an innocent mistake. Eg, the OP creates a new account because the 1st one was created on a different computer & they can't remember their password. Recently, I saw an OP respond to comments under their question by writing an answer, using a different user name. It was a rather confusing experience for all concerned. ;) (Sorry, I can't remember which site it was).

Comment: Misleading title, I was thinking this was a new occurrence of two *completely unrelated* users (different names, pfps, IPs, content, different everything) posting the exact same question within hours of each other that I witnessed 2 or 3 times in the past.

Comment: And the accepted answer on the remaining question is pretty bad... ugh, why can't we have nice things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Closing as a duplicate is good when possible, but you can't close the question as a duplicate if the "original" question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer and if the OP are different (even if it's the same person, the system doesn't know).

Anyway, if you suspect that the same person created several accounts to ask the same question, just use a custom moderator flag on either question and make sure to provide links for the other(s) questions. We already have a lot of flags like this in the queue.

Flagging may result into:

- moderator closing as duplicate (moderators can do that)
- account deletion (not yours but one or several of the duplicated accounts you flagged the questions of)

Comment: I flagged one of the questions for moderator intervention and linked the other question (as well as this discussion) in the flag comment.

Comment: discussions are in progress to improve custom flags and add more categories (duplicate questions, duplicate answers...) let's see if something good comes out

Comment: "Flagging may result into:... account deletion (not yours..." Thanks, now I feel relieved ;)